# Eclipse: Selectively export libraries with Runnable Jar

Tags: java, eclipse

When exporting my Runnable Jar in Eclipse, is there any way to selectively export my libraries i.e. jar files included under the Java Build Path?

The reason I need this is because my Jar is used as a plugin in a larger program, and some of the exported jars can clash and cause errors with existing versions of these jars within the larger program. However I want to keep them in the Java Build Path in order to get the auto-completion suggestions and to not get Undeclared Method errors everywhere.

Comment: If it is a plug-in to something you probably don't want a Runnable Jar at all - just a plain Jar.

Comment: The software its a plugin to does not have the libraries needed to run the plugin. That's why I chose to export it as a runnable, so that I get my libraries added to the file. Should I be doing this in a different way?

Comment: That depends largely on what you are plugging in to - most plugin systems have very specific requirements about how plugin jars are set up.

Comment: @greg-449 thank you for the continued help. When I use a plain Jar it mostly works fine except for a two libraries (openCV343 and mxparser) that then give a Class Not Found error. Could something be up with these particular libraries? 
The work-around I'm using now is to export both a runnable and plain jar, then copy the folders related to these libraries from the runnable to the plain jar. 
It then works but is there a better way?

Comment: As I already said this depends on what you are plugging in to. For example an Eclipse plugin uses the 'Bundle-Classpath', other products use other methods. Possibly one of the three different 'Library handling' methods on the export runnable jar might work.